# Why my html is not working properly in email?

Tags: html, css, email, google-apps-script, bootstrap-4

I'm using app script and create Html Template to send that template to email. The template looks like this.[image]

But then when I send it through app script, it become like this:

[image]

As you can see the box is missing. Even the icons are missing. Any particular reason and solution?

GS Code

```
var emailTemp = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Approved-email").getContent();
  var mailAddress = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue();
  
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress,"Leave Status",'',{
        htmlBody:emailTemp
      });
```

For some reason stack overflow didn't allow me to write HTML code here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>

.card {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    width:300px;
    min-height:400px;
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow:0 20px 50px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border-radius:10px;
    transition:0.5s;
    border-style: dotted;
}
.card:hover {
    box-shadow:0 30px 70px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.card .box {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:100%;
   
}
.card .box .img {
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-radius:10%;
    overflow:hidden;
    
}
.card .box .img img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.card .box h2 {
    font-size:20px;
    color:#262626;
    margin:20px auto;
}
.card .box h2 span {
    font-size:14px;
    background:#e91e63;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:4px 10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.card .box p {
    color:#262626;
}
.card .box span {
    display:inline-flex;
}
.card .box ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.card .box ul li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
}
.card .box ul li a {
    display:block;
    color:#aaa;
    margin:0 10px;
    font-size:20px;
    transition:0.5s;
    text-align:center;
}
.card .box ul li:hover a {
    color:#e91e63;
    transform:rotateY(360deg);
}
</style>



</head>
<body>

<div class="card">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="img">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OWi3x57.gif">
        </div>
        <h2>Hi! John<br><span>Approved</span></h2>
        <p> Details</p>
        <span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tree" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-quora" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your html?`````````````````​`````````````````

Comment: @TheMaster I edited my html. Have a look.

Comment: Hope that helps. Feel free to ask a more specific question if you run into other issues.